# Is it possible to run a query that locates which table contains a row that has over 1 million characters in a single column?

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL database that has 701 tables. I'm trying to replicate this MySQL database into our data warehouse, Snowflake, using a data pipeline tool. Unfortunately, the pipeline tool is running into an error as one of the records in one of these tables contain a single row that has over 1 million characters in a single column.

I'm trying to find out if there's a query that I could use that will look through every single table to identify which row has this offending record. Would this be possible to do at all?

Comment: _"Is it possible to run a query"_ -- yes, it is. What's your actual question?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  This _used to_ exist:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/procedure-analyse.html

Answer (score 0):

Odd that the pipeline tool doesn't provide more context as to which table/column.

[information_schema.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html) contains a `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` and `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` which could indicate which table columns could store 1MB of data.

After that you'd need to query all the possible tables.

If there's a shorter way to do this I don't know it.

Comment: That could be a dozen columns in each of the 701 tables.  It adds up to thousand(s) of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @danblack, you would create a list of tables that *might* contain such long data. That will probably return a subset of your 701 tables. I.e. not all your tables have a column that *could* contain such long data.

Then use `MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(<column>))` to get the greatest length on any row in that table. You need one query per table, because you can put multiple aggregate expressions in each query.

In fact, you could use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query to format the queries you need:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT ',
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(`',COLUMN_NAME,'`)) AS `MAX_',COLUMN_NAME,'_LENGTH`')),
  ' FROM `',TABLE_SCHEMA,'`.`',TABLE_NAME,'`;') AS _query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH >= 1000000
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('mysql','sys','performance_schema','information_schema')
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
```

The result is a set of strings which are themselves SQL queries you can run, one per table.